# Laravel route conflict

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have two routes:

```
Route::get('subjects/{subject}/{tag?}', 'SubjectController@show');
Route::get('subjects/{subject}/{tag}/{lesson}','LessonController@show');
```

When I hit the first route, it works properly but when I hit the second route, I get the following error response:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Is this because laravel is trying to treat the `/{tag}/{lesson}` portion of 2nd route as the value of the parameter of 1st route?

My controller methods are as follows:

```
//SubjectController.php
public function show($subjectSlug, $tag = null)
{
    dd('Inside SubjectController@show');    
}

//LessonController.php
public function show(Subject $subject, Tag $tag, Lesson $lesson)
{
    dd('Inside LessonController@show'); 
}
```

When I visit, say,

> localhost:3000/subjects/mysubject-slug/1

It matches the first route and responds accordingly, but when I visit,

> localhost:3000/subjects/mysubject-slug/1/mylesson-slug

it shows the page not found error. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you clear your routes ? php artisan route:clear

Comment: @CavidKərimov did that, restarted server, no luck...

Comment: It's easy to test whether the first route is taking precedence by just changing their places and see. :) But apart from that, it looks like you're trying to convert slugs for the subject and lesson to models - have you set up route model binding for that correctly?

Comment: Just put the routes in the other order.  More specific routes should go first in general to avoid this issue.

Comment: it shouldn't be blocking it, the router knows what the segments are, there are different segment counts for those 2 routes and as Joel Hinz pointed out via model binding if it can't find the model to bind it will end up with a 404

Comment: I guess you're right about the binding issue, I must have forgotten to explicitly set the route keyname of `Lesson` model to `slug`, which is currently `id` (default).

Comment: actually in your route, you have only one overloaded route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, because of Route Model Binding you can end up with a 404 when the model for the binding can not be retrieved. When using implicit route model binding the primary key will be used to search against by default. This can be changed on the model to use a different field, in this case the `slug` field.

> "If you would like model binding to use a database column other than `id` when retrieving a given model class, you may override the `getRouteKeyName` method on the Eloquent model"
>
> [Laravel 5.5 Docs - Routing - Route Model Binding - Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#implicit-binding)

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your controller to

```
//LessonController.php
public function show($subject, $tag, $lesson)
{
    dd('Inside LessonController@show'); 
}
```

And see if it gets hit. If it does, your binding is done incorrectly.

On the side note, I suppose you don't have `Route::resource()` set up somewhere up in the routes file?